# Creating and using SQL Server spatial view in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql-server, spatial-view

I am using SQL Server 2012 and ArcMap 10.1.

I have created a SQL spatial statement to test out how a) the union function works, and b) how creating a view of this data will work with ArcGIS.

a) the function i'm testing is:

```
SELECT GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate(shape)
FROM CENSUS_TRACTS_2010_2877
WHERE PCT_ASIAN > 5
```

...which gives the following correct result:

[image: Click image for larger version Name: spatialUnion.png Views: 0 Size: 37.9 KB ID: 25497]

b) our database would greatly benefit using a spatial view of our boundary data (using a union, etc.) to display boundaries to our internal users as a single table.

To accomplish this, it seems that a spatial view would be the best use case, as that gives us the option to edit/maintain one file, and the view will serve up a fresh version of the boundaries.

Problem is, when I create the view in SQL Server, it will not show up in ArcMap, and I get the error:

> Warning: Could not add the specified data object to the map.

I think I might be creating the view incorrectly, as this is the field properties ArcMap sees from the view:

[image]

...which doesn't seem correct.

How do I create/register/use a spatial view in ArcMap / SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response from the ArcGIS forum post:

> the problem is that your view does not have something ArcMap
> recognizes as an ObjectID field. ArcMap must have a field that it can
> use as a unique identifier. It is a little tricky to generate a field
> using something like a RowID in SQL Server when you are aggregating a
> single column, but you can do something inelegant like this:
>
> SELECT 1 as ObjectID, GEOMETRY::UnionAggregate(shape) FROM
> CENSUS_TRACTS_2010_2877 WHERE PCT_ASIAN > 5
>
> This will obviously only work in this case when your view is resulting
> in a single record.

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/87428-Spatial-views-from-SQL-Server-2012?p=309422&posted=1#post309422

---

The best way to give ArcMap the ability to use a spatial view is to use a ROW_NUMBER() function to generate OBJECTID's on the features returned in the view.

A good Q&A that describes this process can be found at [How to set up an ArcMap Relate with a table from MS SQL Server 2012](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110945/how-to-set-up-an-arcmap-relate-with-a-table-from-ms-sql-server-2012/110955#110955)

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS has a tool in geodatabase management toolbox: create spatial view. Also you can just save the sql query as a view in SQL and use it in ArcMap. Also you can add a query layer using file add data query layer. All of these options will be a spatial view as long as you include the shape column. One thing to be careful of is versioned data because that is a little more picky about how the data is compiled in SQL. If you're data is already using geometry storage in SQL then look at the views ArcGIS creates in your database, these are already available for you.

Comment: I don't see that GP tool anywhere in my 10.1 toolbox...are you talking about "create versioned view"?

Answer (score 0):

User the RowNumber function in SQL to generate an integer ObjectID field.  Without it ArcMap won't be able to deal with the view.